# ionic2 html page background color whole screen

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic2

This is ionic2 showing in iPad

[image]

This is showing in Iphone 6 plus
[image]

**page.html**

```
<ion-content color="danger">
  <div padding class="about-button">
    <a ion-button color="light" href="tel:123456">
      立即拨打
      </a>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

**page.scss**

```
.about-button {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F44336;
}
```

I don't why in Ipad showing some white screen at the bottom

How can I set the button at the bottom of the page.

First time use ionic, can ionic set something to access all device screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem.

**page.html**

```
<ion-content color="danger">
  <div padding class="about-button">
    <a ion-button color="light" href="tel:123456">
      立即拨打
      </a>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

`ion-content` cannot use `color="danger"`, change it to `<ion-content class="bg-style">` and change scss file also.

**page.scss**

```
.bg-style {
  background: #F44336;
}
```

By this way to solve white screen at bigger size devices